# Javascript - for loop hanging?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, freeze

Maybe I've just been staring at this screen for too long, but I cannot seem to work out why this for loop is hanging?

```
var not = '3,7';
var nots = not.split(',');
alert(nots.length);
for (var i = 0; i <= nots.length; i++) { 
    nots[i] = parseInt(nots[i], 10);
}
document.write(nots);
```

Thanks for any help.

Cheers
Charlie

Comment: Have you considered using Firefox with Firebug. Excellent toolset for debugging Javascript.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the loop you are testing if `i <= nots.length`.  You should be testing if `i < nots.length`.

When the length is 5, there will elements at indexes 0, 1, 2, 3, 4.  So when `i` reaches 5, there are no more elements.  But then you set `nots[i]` (element 5) and extend the array by one.  So each time the loop executes when `i` is equal to `nots.length`, you are extending the array by one, and so the loop runs "just one more time" only to extend the array further.

Comment: Of course!, because I came from a for-in, i didn't think to be counting only to <. Thankyou :)

Comment: One frequently-used pattern to avoid this is `for (var i = 0, l = nots.length; i < l; i++)`